# 3 square wave pulse by 120° phase shift and 3 inverted of each by Arduino

Tags: signal-processing

I want to make a three phase inverter (DC to AC) bridge type using Arduino. For that I want to generate three square wave each is 120° phase shifted and other three waves of main three wave forms inverted for opposite switch.

Can anyone please help me out? I am new to programing in Arduino.

Code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode( 9 , OUTPUT );    
  pinMode( 10 , OUTPUT );   

  TCCR1A = _BV( COM1A0 ) |_BV( COM1B0 );
  TCCR1B = _BV( WGM13) | _BV( WGM12);
  OCR1A = 0;    
}
#define PRESCALER 1
#define PRESCALER_BITS 0x01
#define CLK 16000000UL    

int setWaveforms( unsigned long freq , int shift ) {
  unsigned long clocks_per_toggle = (CLK / freq) / 2;    
  ICR1 = clocks_per_toggle;
  unsigned long offset_clocks = (clocks_per_toggle * shift) / 180UL; 
  OCR1B= offset_clocks;
  TCCR1B |= _BV( CS10 ); 
}

void loop() {
  setWaveforms( 50000 , 120 );
  delay(1000); 
  setWaveforms( 50000 , 120 );
  delay(1000); 
  setWaveforms( 50000 , 120 );
  delay(1000); 
}
```

---

I had get 2 waves only but I want to get 6. I am new to Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question doesn't cut it here, and I doubt it will on Arduino.SE. You need to put in your own research effort and show what you've tried, before we can (and will) help you. Otherwise we're just a free developer for hire.

Comment: ATTiny861. As you've shown no effort, that's all the effort I'll show.